# Wrong edits were accepted by peers, and correct edits were rejected

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I don't know why, but in a specific question on Stack Overflow my edit for removing backticks from aliases was rejected, and edits which use '' in code have been accepted.

This is the revision history of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10169960/revisions and I am referring to the wrongly accepted edit by `Baz1nga`.

Is there any mechanism to watch over peers?
If yes, then why did nothing happen in this case?

My second edit on the same question was accepted but my question is still; "Why wasn't Baz1ng's edit rejected?"

Comment: The user Baz1nga has enough reputation to edit posts without peer-review, so nobody did have to accept his edit.

Comment: @Fabian ok then what if he had done a wrong edit then who will check it?

Comment: Erm, does SQL actually use backticks in its syntax? I don't know SQL, but it seems more likely that it uses single quotes, which makes Baz1nga's edit valid and yours wrong.

Comment: @TheEstablishment '' in the code make different meaning of the code ,which will give result something different which is not required by the poster and `` is also allowed in mysql and you can read tutorial to know that my edit is rite

Comment: The edit from Baz1nga is problematic in many respects, I don't know if backticks are wrong or not, but making the title more generic, not capitalizing the i in the beginning, not fixing the accidental header formatting and not removing the unnecessary parts at the end of the post make it a bad edit.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast That doesn't really help, since that case isn't what happened here. It looks like Baz1nga's edit tripped over the suggested edit and automatically rejected it

Comment: @TheEstablishment MySQL uses backticks to escape field names that collide with reserved keywords (oh, the horrors of non standard crap).

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Not unless he did it spectacularly fast

Comment: my edit is to remove unnessesary `` from the aliases name but Baz1nga`s edit is to remove all `` by '' which made the code worse

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Yeap, probably not...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've fixed the whole thing with my own edit now based on yours, though on looking again Michael Mrozek did the same thing with a better edit and overwrote mine (I missed that your edit didn't return all the backticks). After looking it up quickly, backticks and quotes have different meaning in MySQL and therefore shouldn't be changed, as you could mask the original error by "fixing" the question.

And please everyone try to fix *all* the problems of a post when editing, don't pick out a single one. There were multiple problems with the question, and the first edit made it worse.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like [Baz1nga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350374/baz1nga) submitted an edit 17 seconds after yours was suggested (that is, he was already typing it). He has [enough reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) to edit posts on his own, so his edit automatically rejected yours (which is why it shows up as [rejected by Community](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/241081)).

His edit is semi-terrible (it ignores all the formatting and grammatical problems, and instead only changes the query, which is the one thing he really shouldn't be touching since the question is about an error in the query). The question gets bumped to the front page when it's edited, so in theory somebody should've noticed his edit and done something about it, but it looks like it just got overlooked